# vscode what is this?

Tags: visual-studio-code

[image]

A strange red box appears on the letter when annotating.
This is driving me crazy. How do I solve it?

what is this box?
i don't want to see this box anymore

please help me !!!!!

Comment: Is it possible that VSCode has problems handling the letters of your language? Maybe changing the encoding in the settings helps

Comment: looks like VSCode doesen't know that letter of your language. try changing the font of the editor in the settings. maybe that works

Comment: VSC can mark suspicious Unicode characters, search settings for `unicode`